# Как написать бота для - Whatsapp, как у Telegram, такое возможно?

Tags: whatsapp

Не совсем понятно, как это работает.

Находил один вариант через `selenium`, но при этом создать новые контакты через web.whatsapp - не нашел (или не возможно).

А также второй вариант, который увидел, но не увидел реализацию. Переходишь по ссылке, пишешь, в последующем сразу мне отвечает уже бот.

Кто знает, если не трудно можете помочь. Есть какая-нибудь статья или куда надо мне копать, чтобы разобраться?

Comment: У WhatsApp есть [API](https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api), но доступ выдают не всем.

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. У Воцап есть официальное АПИ. Также как и в телеграм разговор бот не  может начать первым. Пользователь должен сам начать диалог. В этом случае вы получаете бесплатное 24 часовое окно общения с клиентом. 
Однако напрямую к воцап АПИ подключиться нельзя, а только через [партнеров](https://www.facebook.com/business/partner-directory/search?platforms=whatsapp&solution_type=messaging&sort_by=alpha). Каждый партнер берет тарификацию за каждое отправленное сообщение.